# Orientation dependence of electrostatic energies

Tags: electrostatics

I've read that electrostatic interactions (e.g., in a salt crystal) aren't orientation dependent, but the dipole-dipole interaction is given by:

$$U(r)=\frac{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}}{4\pi \epsilon_{0} r_{12}^{3}}(\cos\theta_{12}-3\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2})$$

Then, why does this have a dependence on the angle? The angle $\theta_{12}$ is the angle between two oppositely charged dipoles $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$, and the other two angles are the angles formed by the dipoles with respect to the lines connecting their centers.

Answer (score 0):

The electrostatic interaction depends on the field, generated by charges. The field doesn't depend on angle to the charge, but depends on charge's position. So, for dipole (consisting of two charges), the angle contain information about the each position of a charge relative to another charge. So instead of knowing the positions of each charge we can contain information about position of whole dipole and dipole angle. Each dipole approximately generates the field:

[image]

It depend's on angle, because it consist of two fields from both negative and positive charge in dipole and for one angle positive charge can be further than negative (so field mostly feel the positive influence) and for another angle it can be conversely, so that's why the electric interaction between dipole and anything else depends on dipole orientation.

[image]

For any other specifications I think you should just check the derivation of dipole interaction formula: https://janheyda.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/electrostatics-multipoles.pdf
It's just pure math